# match mysql wildcard entries in table to query

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing an email application in PHP and want to check if an email address has been excluded from sending for some reason.
So far, I have a MySQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists ddt
(
    ddtID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID int NOT NULL,
    ddtFrom text(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'From address or part off, can match start or end only',
    CONSTRAINT ddt_users_userID_fk FOREIGN KEY (ddtID) REFERENCES users (userID)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ddt_ddtID_uindex ON ddt (ddtID);
```

(`ddt = Don't Deliver To`)
I have no problems if I enter a whole email address in the table, as that can be queried with a standard: `select * from ddt where ddtFrom='test@example.com';`

What I can't work out (or get my head around) is how to match partial email addresses.
eg. ddt table contains

```
|ddtID |UserID |ddtFrom|
|1     |1      |%@example.com|
|2     |1      |noreply@%|
```

I want to find if any of the following email addresses shouldn't be delivered to:

```
john@example.com
jo@example.co.uk
noreply@theendoftheworld.org
hello@kitty.tv
```

(only jo@example.co.uk & hello@kitty.tv should get emails).

If I was doing it the other way around (matching a wildcard against a table) then i could just do: `select * From ddt where ddtFrom like '%.example.com';` but I want to use the wildcards IN the table.

Any help greatly appreciated, or if someone can think of another way to approach this that would be great too.

(Currently using MySQL 5.7 but can upgrade if required)

Comment: In SQL the wildcard character is `%`. Please try `select * from ddt where ddtFrom like '%@example.com';`.

Comment: Hi Aulis, Issue isn't searching for entries in the table with a wildcard in my query, its about having wildcards in the TABLE and having that match the query. I have modified the question toi show the correct wildcard character though.

Comment: Guess I read your question a little too fast. Can you please try it with concat'ing the wildcard in the query? Can't remember the syntax, but it isn't very hard. No need to add the wildcards in to your tables.

Comment: The field size was set at 50 along with the userID was the minimal i need for testing at present, as i am not testing with email addys longer than 50 chars.
Ability to block entire domains or to block an email addy starting with 'noreply' followed by anything (both before and after the @ sign) allow blocking emails that contain 'noreply' or similar to cut down on spam email.  Ability to not send emails to an entire domain could be used to avoid sending emails to anyone@superuser.com or the likes (as these would always be information emails).

Comment: Aulis, not sure what you mean by contacting the wildcards in the query.
The query would be something like "select * from ddt where ddtEmail matches 'no-one@exmple.com'" (i know thats not correct SQL syntax, its an example of what i am trying to do).  Currently the only way i can do this is to read each record from the DDT table and then use PHP to compare each individual ddtEmail record to each email in a list.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the email list is in PHP, this part of the script generates auto replies for incoming emails, so email address is read from mailbox, compared to the list of 'Dont Deliver To' (or another name i suppose could be 'Do Not Reply To' in this part of the script).  Kind of like an out of office type system that you can exclude certain domains and/or email addresses from, so i cant put the 'wildcard' into the query from PHP unless i read the entire DDT table into an array and then use a foreach loop to check for a match.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this would be to build a table of the emails you want to check in your query (using a `SELECT ... UNION SELECT` structure) and then `CROSS JOIN`ing that to `ddt`, testing whether each email address was `LIKE` each of the `ddtFrom` values. Since MySQL treats booleans as 0 or 1 in a numeric context, you can then use `MAX` as the equivalent of an `OR` function to determine if an email matched one (or more) of the exclusion strings. e.g.

```
SELECT email, MAX(email LIKE ddtFrom) AS excluded
FROM (SELECT CONVERT('john@example.com' USING latin1) AS email
      UNION SELECT 'jo@example.co.uk'
      UNION SELECT 'noreply@theendoftheworld.org'
      UNION SELECT 'hello@kitty.tv') e
CROSS JOIN ddt
GROUP BY email
HAVING excluded = 0
```

Output:

```
email               excluded
hello@kitty.tv      0
jo@example.co.uk    0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pdze7Z5V3f5rmVm7wzQkyS/0)

Note that I had to use a `CONVERT` to get dbfiddle's implicit character types for the two tables to match, you may not require that on your system in which case just use `SELECT 'john@example.com' AS email` as the first line of the table building query.